# How long do I have to be away from Norway if I am required to leave but then allowed to come back?

Tags: norway, hungarian-citizens

The [Norwegian Directorate of Immigration website for jobseekers](https://www.udi.no/en/want-to-apply/work-immigration/duty-to-report-for-job-seekers-who-are-eueea-nationals/?c=hun) in the country says:

- If you do not get a job within six months, you must leave Norway.
- You can then come back to Norway anytime to search for work.

If I don't find a job within 6 months, can I just cross the border to Finland & come back immediately? Or am I required to be away for some more time than that? I am a Hungarian citizen.

Comment: Looks like _Hungarian_ (the link has it included) - but it's probably the same for all EU citizens.

Comment: Nobody will notice you’ve crossed the border to finland...

Comment: Yepp, I am hungarian. Alright, thanks everyone!

Comment: @zabop Simply put, you cannot and will not be deported from Norway; however you may well be refused entry to Finland, as their borders are closed for most non-citizens/residents

Comment: Thank you @Crazydre.